# DateTime AddMonths is multiplying instead

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a program that keeps track of bills. If a bill is recurring monthly, I want to add those dates (up to a year) to a list.

```
//code changed for brevity but same principle applies
private List<Bill> GenerateRecurring(Bill bill)
{
  //bill.DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10/14/2017");
  var Bills = new List<Bill>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
  {
      var newBill = bill;
      newBill.DueDate = bill.DueDate.AddMonths(i);
      Bills.Add(newBill);
  }
  return Bills;
}
```

I expected the elements in Bills to have the dates 11/14/2017, 12/14/2017, etc, but instead they are 11/14/2017, 1/14/2018, 4/14/2018, etc.

Is 'bill.DueDate' being updated each time in the loop or am I missing something?

Comment: Assigning bill to newBill does not copy the object, but just has both variables point to the same object instance. You need to explicitly add a method to the Bill class to create a new instance of the class with the same values.

Comment: save your dueDate before the loop and use that to create new dates for your bills

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var newBill = bill;` does not create a new bill from the existing bill, it just gives the existing bill another name to refer to it. So you are always updating the same object and adding the same object to the `Bills` collection (after your loop, `Bills` will contain your single bill 12 times)
.

Comment: also Bills list should be in the method scope

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually with your `var newBill = bill` line.  This does not create a new bill, but is actually just a reference to your old bill.  As a result, every time the loop is executed, the same date is being incremented.